# Clone schema with new name for SQL Sever Multi-Tenant design using same database

Tags: sql-server

Similar questions have been asked in several posts but I don't see an answer that fits my needs exactly.  If this has been answered and I've missed it then please share the link.

I am using sql server 2016 with one database that I want to use separate schemas for multi-tenants.  Let's say the dbo schema is the "default template" and whenever a new subscriber signs up then I want to create a new duplicate schema (including all tables, views, indexes, etc. and name the schema the same as their company name. Also, some of the tables are used as lookups in the frontend application so I'll also want to copy the data for specific tables but not all of them.  I have a script for creating the user and schema but not copying all the tables with some data.  SQL Server is not my strong suit but based on my research the same database/separate schema seems to be the best approach from my frontend application.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem/question? there are many ways to achieve the goal. using tools, scripts or custom programming...

Comment: The question is how to create a script (or any other method but script is preferable) to accomplish the above.  If a user requests a new subscription then I will create a user account with login, create a new schema with their company name as the id and set the schema as their default.  What I don't know how to do is clone the "template" schema including all objects and some data to the new schema.

Comment: I used SSMS to generate scripts but then I ran into dependency issues.

Comment: Specifically in the SQL Server case are you looking for separate “schemas” such that you could backup and restore independently of other “schemas”. Do you want to have the ability to back up a “schema” on one server and restore that clients “schema” and all its data on another database server?  Do you have a requirement that at any part of your application where a query pulls data from two different client schemas at the same time.   Would you be OK having all “schemas” in one big backup file for all clients.  So if you keep adding clients you would just get a bigger server?

Comment: I hadn't given much thought to backing up the data but backing up all schemas in one big file would probably suffice but I think I'd need the ability to restore an individual schema if need be. No queries would ever pull data from two different schemas. The frontend app is the same for all clients and each would have their own unique set of identical tables. I haven't ruled out separate databases which I would be able to do without any help but I believe it will be cost inhibitive although I'm rechecking pricing with the hosting service.

Comment: Have you found solution?